# Adding a key with "ssh-add" works but passing it with "-i" doesn't

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-agent

I have a case like follows:

```
ssh -J${some-jump-host} -i some-key.pem opc@${some-ip}
```

which does not ask for the key password for `some-key.pem` but directly fail as it is not authenticated.

However, if I do:

```
ssh-add -K some-key.pem
ssh -J${some-jump-host} opc@${some-ip}
```

this asks the password when adding the key, then it works.

I have

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Include ~/ssh_config

Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    User my-username

IdentityFile path-to-an-irrelevant-key
IdentityFile path-to-some-other-irrelevant-key
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 10
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
```

in `~/ssh_config` we just define some hosts and proxy jumps, and this:

```
Host *
    User my-username
    PKCS11Provider /Library/OpenSC/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
    ForwardAgent yes 
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

so my question is, why ssh seem to be ignoring the key when it is passed with `-i`?

**Note:**
this is the relevant output of the `-vvv` for the case with `-i`

```
debug1: Will attempt key: some-key.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
```

Comment: But what is the key for? The jump host? Or the destination host?

Comment: key is for destination host. I'm authenticated with jump host using "yubikey" (I think jump host relevant line is `PKCS11Provider /Library/OpenSC/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so`)